# Was bedeutet "eindecken" bei Versicherungen?

Tags: meaning, technical-terminology

Ich sehe mich hier gerade mit Formulierungen à la

> Bitte die Versicherung eindecken.

konfrontiert. Dazu scheint es auch das Adjektiv

> eindeckbar

zu geben.

Ich habe das Wort "eindecken" noch nie in dieser Verwendung gehört (ich kenne "eindecken" ausschließlich im Sinn von "ausstatten", "mit Vorräten/Ausrüstung versehen") und weiß nicht so recht, was ich damit anfangen soll. Ist das Versicherungsjargon?

Merkwürdigerweise hilft mir Google dieses Mal auch nicht weiter. Bei der Suche nach der Bedeutung von "eindecken" mit "Versicherung" erhalte ich zwar zahlreiche Treffer, aber offenbar praktisch keine "echten" Vorkommen der Wörter, sondern nur Links zu diversen Deutsch-Englisch-Wörterbüchern.

Diese Funde legen nahe, dass "eine Versicherung eindecken" einfach "etwas versichern" bzw. "etwas durch eine Versicherung schützen" bedeutet - aber dann frage ich mich, ob "eindecken" noch eine spezielle Variante davon impliziert (ggf. einen vollständigen Schutz ohne Eigenbeteiligung?).

Comment: Ein klein wenig mehr Kontext wäre eventuell hilfreich.

Comment: Der Fachjargon kommt vermutlich von der zweiten Bedeutung im [Dudeneintrag](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/eindecken). Ich würde vermuten, dass, erst wenn die Eindeckung erfolgt ist, die Absicherung für den Schadensfall existiert. Also, man beantragt Versicherungsschutz über einen Makler, der Schutz existiert aber erst, wenn die Versicherung zustimmt (eindeckt). Um sicher zu gehen, wäre vermutlich die Nachfrage bei einem Versicherungsmakler oder ähnlichen Fachmenschen nötig.

Comment: Wer sagt das zu wem? Ich könnte mir (ohne konkrete Ahnung) vorstellen, dass dies *innerhalb* einer Versicherungsgesellschaft geschieht, damit im Rahmen eines Vertragsabschlusses mit einem Kunden im Hintergrund die *Deckungssumme* für den Schadensfall anteilmäßig "bereitgehalten" wird / entspechend rückversichert wird ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Eindeckung einer Versicherung" ist ein Fachbegriff im Zusammenhang mit Transportrisiken von Spediteuren. Vgl. z.B. [hier](http://178.63.40.151/dslv/web.nsf/gfx/33A29E39CB6A7F21C125832A003F721D/$file/Leitfaden%20Versicherungsschutz%20nach%20den%20ADSp%20(Stand%20Oktober%202018).pdf) Abschnitt 1.1 "Besorgung von Versicherungsschutz durch Auftrag" oder [hier](https://www.adsp-haftung.de/adsp-2017/21/).

"Eindecken" assoziiert man oft mit Redewendungen wie "Tisch eindecken" oder "Dach eindecken". Das passt hier natürlich nicht. Im Kontext der Frage wird das das Wort im Sinne von "sich mit etwas eindecken" verwendet. Vgl. auch [hier](https://wissen.consorsbank.de/t5/Geldlexikon/Eindeckung/ta-p/2849) in Kontext mit Börsensgeschäften:

> Unter Eindeckung versteht man das Gegengeschäft zum Leerverkauf, bei dem der Verkäufer die verkauften, aber nicht in seinem Besitz befindlichen Wertpapiere an der Börse beschaffen muss, um diese zum Erfüllungszeitpunkt liefern zu können.

PS. Der Vollständigkeit halber noch weitere Zitate:

Aus oben erwähntem Abschnitt 1.1 "Besorgung von Versicherungsschutz durch Auftrag (Herbvorhebungen von mir):

> Nach Ziffer 21.1 ADSp 2017 **besorgt der Spediteur die Versicherung des Guts, in der Regel eine Transport-oder Lagerversicherung, wenn der Auftraggeber den Spediteur vor Übergabe des Guts damit beauftragt. Sofern der Auftraggeber dem Spediteur keine Weisungen erteilt, ist er in der Wahl des Versicherers frei und hat die Versicherung unter Berücksichtigung der Interessen des Auftraggebers einzudecken.** Insbesondere hat der Spediteur mangels Weisung nach pflichtgemäßem Ermessen über Art und Umfang der Versicherung zu entscheiden und sie zu marktüblichen Bedingungen abzuschließen. Dieser dem Spediteur eingeräumte Ermessensspielraum trägt der Praxis des Massengeschäfts Rechnung und lässt Spielraum für ein ergeb-nisorientiertes Vorgehen im schnellen Tagesgeschäft. Soll ein Transportrisiko versichert werden, **wird der Spediteur die Eindeckung einer Transportversicherung zu vollen Bedingungen („all risk“) in die Wege leiten.** Denn es ist davon auszugehen, dass die Interessen des Auftraggebers darauf ausgerichtet sind, die Transportrisiken so umfassend wie möglich abzusichern. Hiervon ist auch bei der Versicherung von stationären Lagerrisiken auszugehen, so dass der Spediteur nicht nur das Feuerrisiko, sondern auch die Risiken Einbruchdiebstahl, Leitungswasser und Sturm (oder andere Elementarschäden) zu versichern hat. Anders als bei einer Transportversicherung werden hier standardmäßig aber keine Policen angeboten, die diese stationären Risiken gegen alle Gefahren versichern; mit anderen Worten: Bei einer Lagerversicherung ist nicht jeder Verlust (einschließlich Inventurdifferenzen) und jede Beschädigung versichert. Deshalb ist für die Besorgung von Versicherungsschutz wichtig, dass jeder Spediteur berücksichtigt, dass Lagerrisiken sich teilweise auch im Rahmen einer Transportversicherung abdecken lassen. Denn eine Transportversicherung stellt nicht nur Versicherungsschutz für dieGüter zur Verfügung, soweit sie in Bewegung sind, sondern es genügt Bewegungsbereitschaft. Diese Möglichkeit sehen die vom Gesamtverband der Deutschen Versicherungswirtschaft (GDV) empfohlenen DTV-Güter 2000/2011 auch vor, ohne die Dauer des Versicherungsschutzes konkret vorzugeben. In den Versicherungsverträgen wird für transportbedingte Vor-, Zwischen-und Nachlagerungen Versicherungsschutz für einen Zeitraum zwischen 30 und 60 Tagen gewährt. **Kann der Spediteur wegen der Art der zu versichernden Güter oder aus einem anderen Grund keinen Versicherungsschutz eindecken**, bestimmt Ziffer 21.5 ADSp 2017, dass der Spediteur dies dem Auftraggeber unverzüglich, also ohne schuldhaftes Zögern mitzuteilen hat. **Die Gründe, die es dem Spediteur unmöglich machen, Versicherungsschutz zu besorgen, können vielfältig sein.** Möglicherweise will der Versicherer bestimmte hochwertige oder diebstahlgefährdete Güter nicht, nur auf Anfrage oder unter Auflagen versichern. **Die Eindeckung von Versicherungsschutz kann auf bestimmten Relationen auch durch gesetzliche Vorschriften (zum Beispiel Embargovorschriften) nicht möglich sein.** Bei Lagerrisiken kommt häufig hinzu, dass die Versicherer ohne weitergehende Informationen in Bezug auf das einzulagernde Gut oder die Lagerräumlichkeiten keinen Versicherungsschutz zur Verfügung stellen.

Aus dem zweiten Link:

> ADSp 2017 §21 Versicherung des Gutes

21.1 Der Spediteur besorgt die Versicherung des Gutes (z. B. Transport- oder Lagerversicherung) bei einem Versicherer seiner Wahl, wenn der Auftraggeber ihn damit vor Übergabe des Gutes beauftragt.

21.2 Der Spediteur hat die Versicherung des Gutes zu besorgen, wenn dies im Interesse des Auftraggebers liegt. Der Spediteur darf dies insbesondere vermuten, wenn

21.2.1 der Spediteur bei einem früheren Verkehrsvertrag im Rahmen noch laufender Geschäftsbeziehung eine Versicherung besorgt hat,

21.2.2 der Auftraggeber im Auftrag einen „Warenwert für eine Versicherung des Gutes“ angegeben hat.

21.3 Die Vermutung des Interesses an der Eindeckung einer Versicherung nach Ziffer 21.2 besteht insbesondere nicht, wenn

21.3.1 der Auftraggeber die Eindeckung untersagt,

21.3.2 der Auftraggeber ein Spediteur, Frachtführer oder Lagerhalter ist.

21.4 Der Spediteur hat bei der Besorgung einer Versicherung Weisungen des Auftraggebers insbesondere hinsichtlich Versicherungssumme und der zu deckenden Gefahren zu befolgen. Erhält er keine Weisung, hat der Spediteur nach pflichtgemäßem Ermessen über Art und Umfang der Versicherung zu entscheiden und sie zu marktüblichen Bedingungen abzuschließen.

21.5 Kann der Spediteur wegen der Art der zu versichernden Güter oder aus einem anderen Grund keinen Versicherungsschutz eindecken, hat der Spediteur dies dem Auftraggeber unverzüglich mitzuteilen.

21.6 Besorgt der Spediteur nach Vertragsabschluss auf Weisung des Auftraggebers eine Versicherung, übernimmt er die Einziehung eines Entschädigungsbetrags oder sonstige Tätigkeiten bei Abwicklung von Versicherungsfällen und Havareien, so steht ihm auch ohne Vereinbarung eine ortsübliche, ansonsten angemessene Vergütung neben dem Ersatz seiner Auslagen zu.

Comment: Danke für das Zitat der letzten Quelle. Wäre es sinnvoll, aus den ersten beiden Quellen die passenden Zitate auch unterzubringen?

Comment: Ist diese Verwendung auf das Transportwesen beschränkt, oder verwenden auch andere Branchen diesen Begriff im Zusammenhang mit Versicherungen?

Comment: Eine kurze Suche legt nahe, dass dieser Begriff so tatsächlich nur im Transportwesen verwendet wird.

Comment: @Shegit Brahm Im Gegensatz zum eingefügten Zitat enthalten die beiden anderen Links keine expliizite Definition des Begriffs, man kann es nur aus dem Kontext erschließen. Ich habe mal eine längere Passage eingefügt, die das deutlich macht. Allerdings ist es mühsam zu lesen.

Comment: @Hulk Soweit ich weiß, ist es auf das Transportwesen beschränkt. Die Hand kann ich aber nicht dafür ins Feuer legen.

Comment: *"Dach eindecken". Das passt hier natürlich nicht.*" Man müsste sich bloß vorstellen, ein hinreichender Schutz wird mit einer Abdeck-Plane ausreichend versichert. Dies hat natürlich der Transporteur zu besorgen. Dann würde einiges für eine Beschränkung auf das Transportwesen deuten. Allerdings wird *abgedeckt*, sowie Engl. *cover* vielfältig gesagt. Vorstellbar wären auch anderer Ursprünge da Transport international ist. vgl. etwa Rendite, Rente (eine Art Versicherung, "Nebenform von lateinisch reddere ... „zurückgeben“", s. Kaution, Deposit), Engl. *deed*, Ger. *Tat* (dazu evtl. *eintüten*).