# What is the difference between "Bierdeckel" vs. "Deckel"?

Tags: etymology, regional

*Deckel*s cover the coreferent, naturally. Every Topf has its Deckel, after all. *Deckelbecher* certainly exist and may appear archaic. Covering one's beaverage may be a good idea. But this one sits under it. One may wonder in view of this: Why is the *Bierdeckel* ("coaster") called the way it is?

Compound words are in the majority not indexed in dictionaries, so I come empty handed, save for a few notes.

**For reference** (cf. Wiktionary):

- *Gedeck* more generally refers to cutlery (as in *Tische decken* "to set tables"), or dishes (*Herrengedeck*, like Nl. *bittergarnitur*). *Tischdecke* or *Tischtuch* ("cloth")  is close enough to *Filz* (cp. *Bierfilz*), or *Serviette* (further use as *Sabberlatz* is optional). Case closed?
- *Deckel* also names a running bill in pubs, a credit system of one kind or another (En. *tab*).
- [eindecken](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/58973/was-bedeutet-eindecken-bei-versicherungen?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C61.3482) of financial jargon has been in question and remains without answer.
- Pfeifer likewise reports that *[decken](https://dwds.de/wb/Deckel)* is "in der Kaufmannssprache ‘finanziell aufkommen, absichern’," but his etymology on *Deckel* ("15. Jh.", op. cit.) is unreliable for it omits Dutch *decksel*.
- Other senses of *-deck-* may be questionable as well.
- The reconstructions are usually presented without doubt. Inherent uncertainty needs to be understood with Proto-Germanic reconstruction and beyond that PIE, which Pfeifer quotes in general agreement with Pokorny. For one, the [s-mobile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-mobile) in PIE *(s)teg- remains unexplained. *teg- on the other hand is uncertain with regards to *deg-, *to take*. *ten- has a couple root-extensions which are unexplained. Etc. p. p. Therefore, a precise etymology of *Bierdeckel* may be desirable. (Extended discussion of a couple hundred items omited for brevities sake).
- *Auf den Deckel, die Mütze* – *eins auf den Deckel kriegen* ("to get a slap on the wrist") - is not usually understood as equivalent to *Das geht auf meine Kappe* ("that's on me", "somebodies responsibility"). Although, dialectal *Deckel* ("hat") may be synonym to *Kappe* ("cap") in that sense. See also *Lappen* "(drivers) license" , *den Löffel abgeben*, funny *figures* of speech like that.
- *Deckeln* "to cap", as regards Berliner *Mietendeckel*, is more often collocated with *Schulden*.
- En. *tab* has been plausibly explained as short for *tabula, tabulatur*.

  - A direct comparison to *Deckel* may appear unlikely, *declaration* or *calculation* no less, because there is no obvious way for it to end as coaster under a beer.
  - Conversely, *back of the envelope, napkin calculation* are meaningful tangents, but may be independent developments.

Fineprint: I have received tremendous flack for previous etymology questions. So, I want to keep this simple. No speculation, only credible references. Naturally, this means no speculative sources. This holds even if the author is usually reliable, unless you feel comfortable in a position to judge the claim – ie. it is not automatically the correct answer unless you can support it with sufficient evidence. Rinse and repeat.

Answer (score 2):

Der Bierdeckel ist ein Deckel, weil er ursprünglich dazu gedacht ist, auf das Bierglas gelegt zu werden, um im Biergarten oder sonst im Freien dafür zu sorgen, dass keine Insekten in das Bier gelangen.

The *Bierdeckel* is a *Deckel* (a "lid"), because its original intent is to cover the beer glass in order to prevent insects from falling into the beer (in a beer garden or elsewhere outdoors).

Comment: Hab jetzt erst das Kleingedruckte in der Frage gelesen :) Das kann ich nicht erfüllen, meine Quelle ist mein Opa :D Aber auch Wikipedia kennt diese Geschichte: https://www.wikiwand.com/de/Bierdeckel

Comment: "its original intent" - that means it has gone full circle now? Originally meant as a lid to be put on top of the glass against flies, it transformed into something the glass is put onto ... from where it gets repurposed these days as a lid to be put on top of the glass against flies again?